# What must be the case for "$\forall x\in U,P(x)$" and "$\forall x\in U,\text{not } P(x)$" both to be true?

Tags: logic

> What must be the case if both the statements are true?
>
> - Statement 1: $\forall x \in U, P(x)$
> - Statement 2: $\forall x \in U, \text{not } P(x)$

Please help me out here. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there is any $x\in U$, it can't be the case that both statements are true.

Comment: The question is whats the case if both the statements are true, not when both the statements are not true.

Comment: saulspatz told you about *all* cases where $U$ has some element. $~$ So, what happens in that *other* case?

Comment: "All natural number are Even" and "All natural numbers are not-Even (i.e. Odd)": it is clearly an impossible situation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we are working in a logic system that a statement and its negation can't both be true:

We have for anything $x$.

If $x \in U$ then $P(x)$.  But if $x \in U$ then $\lnot P(x)$.  Thus if $x\in U$ then $P(x)$ and $\lnot P(x)$.  But that conclusion is always false.

So we have:  If $x \in U$ then FALSEHOOD.  That the only way we can have: If $Q$ then FALSEHOOD be true, is if $Q$ is false.

So we have $\lnot (x \in U)$.

SO for anything $x$ we have $x \not \in U$.  So $U$ can not have any elements.

So $U = \emptyset$.

And that is enough:.   For all $x \in U$ anything may vacuously be concluded as there are no $x \in U$.

Comment: In first order logic, definition of model excludes empty sets.

Comment: It does?  Really?  Well, that's fine.  then these are never both true.  Unless you are in logic system that always Q and not Q simultaneously.  This really depends on context.  But I think we can all agree that if $U$ is not empty then there are $x$ where both $P(x)$ and $\lnot P(x)$ are simultaneously true, which in a system that acknowledges contradictions is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose both statements are indeed true and $U$ is non-empty. Hence $$ \forall x \in U P(x) $$ and $$ \forall x \in U \lnot P(x) $$ both hold. Pick your favourite $y \in U$. Then $P(y)$ is true since $P(x)$ holds for any $x \in U$, so in particular for your picked $y$. By the same reasoning, $\lnot P(y)$ is also true. In conclusion $$ P(y) \land \lnot P(y)$$ is true, which is a contradiction. We say your system of formulas is inconsistent. In other words, there is no structure $U$ that satisfies both formulas at the same time -- we say the system has no models.

Another way of looking at this is the following: you can show that the formulas $$ \forall x \in U \lnot P(x)$$ and $$ \lnot \exists x \in U P(x) $$ are logically equivalent (i.e. a structure $U$ satisfies the first formula iff it satisfies the second). If now both of your stated formulas are true, then so is the formula $$ \forall x \in U P(x) \land \lnot \exists x \in U P(x) $$ which is obviously a contradiction.

Comment: No. It is equivalent to: $\neg \exists x\in U~\neg P(x)\wedge\neg\exists x\in U~P(x)$, which is not a contradiction.  It can be satisfied by some interpretation of $U$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Assuming $U$ is non-empty (and that is a very common assumption) it certainly is a contradiction -- what interpretation of $U$ allows no witness for neither $P$ nor for its negation?

Comment: "Assuming U is non-empty (and that is a very common assumption)"  But not a stated one.  No-where does it say that $U$ is not empty.

Comment: @fleablood I see, thanks for the heads up both of you!

Answer (score 0):

In classical logic : $$\forall xPx\land\forall x\lnot Px\xrightarrow{\text{by taking any $x\in U$}}Px\land\lnot Px\vdash_c\perp,$$ a contradiction.